# Possible To Rename Hardware Name of Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, multi-boot

Is it possible to rename a hard drive's hardware name? (The name that shows up in the BIOS, or with Disk Utility in a Mac)?

eg:

```
WD1502FAEX
```

I'm asking because I'm about to get two identical hard drives, and I don't want them to be a pain to distinguish in between when formatting or booting.

Comment: That information seems to be stored on the device item itself (as in firmware of the drive). I can't figure out which is which half the time myself :-). Only tips would be , The port it is on (sata ports are numbered) It can be Partition different to provide clues. Names, not letters, because letters are assigned, make sure you put Name labels on disk/partitions.  I have even gone to the extent of adding the array and port info to the name because it will show up in most locations.  During setup add One or 2 at a time, so you know which is which, small sticker on wires and drive show port.

Comment: I always thought the bios or utility should list drives by serial number, would make more sense and put a stop to the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your best option is to manually determine the drives by plugging the first drive into the SATA port, give it a NAME in your OS (Windows or Linux), label the cable physically, and then attach the second drive to SATA and give it a label.

Comment: Damn, was hoping there was a hack or something. I'm sure there's a good reason why it's this way-- but it sure is a pain in a multi-drive setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to change the hardware disk drive title only for your computer the you can follow these steps. The name of any device can be modified with this method and can help you organize your devices better in Device Manager and in properties tab. Below are the steps to rename mouse hardware title same method can be used to rename HDD or SDD hardware title.

First, open Device Manager by opening a run prompt (Windows Key + R) and typing devmgmt.msc. You can also access the Device Manager via the Control Panel.

[image: Capture.PNG]

Next, find the device that you want to change the name of. Since I want to change the name of my "HID-compliant Mouse", I will look for that. The devices are organized nicely into categories, so you shouldn't have any issues finding the right one.

[image]

Right click on the device and select Properties. Then go to the Details tab and pick "Driver key" from the dropdown list. Copy the value by right clicking it and selecting "Copy".

[image]

Open the Registry Editor by opening a run prompt and typing regedit. Grant administrator privileges if prompted to do so.

[image]

Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > ControlSet001 > Enum

[image]

Right click on the Enum key and select "Permissions...".

[image]

On the screen that appears, click "Add..."

In the "Enter the object names to select" text field, type the name of the user currently logged into the computer. For instance, my username is "Brandon" so I type Brandon and press the "Check Names" box. If entered correctly, the rest will be filled out for you automatically. Click OK to exit that screen.

[image]

Still on the permissions page, click "Advanced" then navigate to the "Owner" tab. Select the current user of the computer as the owner and tick the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" checkbox. Click Apply and then OK a few times to exit those windows.

[image]

Still on the permissions page, left click your username to select it, then tick the checkbox titled "Full Control". Click "Apply". If done properly, you have just given yourself permissions to edit Enum and all of its subkeys.

[image]

Back in Regedit, left click on the "Enum" key to select it. Then press CTRL + F to open the search prompt. Paste the driver key you copied earlier and search.

[image]

The search should take you to the properties of the device you want to edit. Right click on a blank space and select New > String Value. Name this string "FriendlyName" (without the quotations).

Double-click on the FriendlyName variable to modify it. In the textfield, type the name you want your device to have.

[image]

Go back to Device Manager and go to Action > Scan for hardware changes. If you followed these steps properly, the device should now be renamed.

[image]

[Here](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/tutorial-how-to-change-device-names-in-device-manager.15321/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=aaac2d1cb79aafaee2827c4b3daa0d7a7592e4c8-1623754493-0-AQYx_Yq4HoZyd39SUYoIA7UMkBGNEKJazNZId5edSIvtVMyve12K6cnJqVd3-9LzlW5u5pwrI8CRCI0kM3lZjZ3pDaX_9NuQZN4WrablR-Z8z1uKewMZOGU6Y_TvuWepphA_J-dlEeiflLLYS2tDxaILjFl1-T7tpnZFzVIXfzPw61gkQxxtvcm1H9cH1w8mBIta4ZtyTF6x3CNM9GJxKLu1x5TCwXIEv0gCOzXU6HNsYrSvQC5G85DkGge7W3RUjja-2kkC2zMikozH1XFlMuHhIWSZHLzpp0GkVZsf8hl6FZOFfw6kYbxymhG-03hwh8DI-GkFFQTrkKTMn-JI6PBnj2iYiUnT9-EeipI_OH55DEaIGORRo0dDdUWh2OlSxAluueCnjP5gCwT19QAXOElC8FcTx8sLEwP6_-x-yDKjzIcvezta6oil4T7CUQ9_HBl5L6TXNLZ_xNGIwb1ZrLts1cMbyQEz7-UEtMYsfXVU) is the original thread.

Comment: This indeed changes the names in device manager but not in boot. I'm on gigabyte Z690 windows 10

Answer (score -1):

It takes a simple cmd command with bcdedit; tested on win10 and win11.

open cmd; In `c:/windows/system32` type `bcdedit command`.

this shows the windows boot loaders.

change the description to identify the drive in bios:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} description "this is windows 10 drive"
```

can also change description for `{current}` to avoid confusion, but that doesn't show in bios.

I'm on gigabyte mobo.

Comment: If the video goes down, your answer would essentially be useless. You might want to edit in the essential details, using the video as a *reference*, then flag this answer for undeletion